# how to detect socket.io event which is not registered?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm using node.js and socket.io for a chat program and I listen to some events. Here is the relevant code:

```
server: io.sockets.on('connection',( socket ) => {
    socket.on('joinRoom',( data )=>{ do with message });
    socket.on('leaveRoom',( data )=>{ do with message });
}
client: io.emit('joinRoom',{uid:11});
```

If the client emits an event which is not registered as `io.emit('noEvent',{});`, how does the server detect it?

Answer (score 1):

> Use **socketio-wildcard** plugin.

You can use the [wildcard](https://github.com/hden/socketio-wildcard) plugin for socket IO to do that as suggested in SocketIO official documentation [here](https://socket.io/docs/faq/#Can-I-use-wildcards-in-events), like so:

```
socket.on('*', function(packet){
  // client.emit('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
  packet.data === ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the socket server is listening for something to happen on the port not the 'event'. So if something is 'emitted' and there is a 'listener' it will pick that up, it just won't know exactly what to do with it.

Not sure if this will help but here is the socket.io [cheetsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 0):

In 3.x, it can be done without any plugins using [`onAny` listener](https://socket.io/docs/v3/listening-to-events/#socket-onAny-listener):

```js
socket.onAny((eventName, ...args) => {
  const isNotRegistered = !Object.keys(socket._events).includes(eventName)
  
  if (isNotRegistered) {
    // Event is not registered
  }
})
```